# Oracle : Grant select on a View

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to perform a select operation on a view which contains a few tables as follows

```
SELECT count(1) FROM ABC_DEF.MY_VIEW;
```

The view :

```
SELECT TEXT FROM DBA_VIEWS where OWNER = 'ABC_DEF' and VIEW_NAME  = 'MY_VIEW' ;

Result : SELECT "COL_1", "COL_2" FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.COL_1, B.COL_2 FROM ABC.TABLE_1 A, XYZ.TABLE_2 B WHERE A.COL_3 = B.COL_3)
```

In order to do this, I try to grant select access to the role I use

```
GRANT SELECT ON ABC_DEF.MY_VIEW TO MY_READ_ROLE;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for 'XYZ.TABLE_2'
```

Then I try to grant select to the table itself

```
GRANT SELECT ON XYZ.TABLE_2 TO MY_READ_ROLE;

Grant succeeded.
```

And then I try to perform the grant on the view again, but I still get the same error. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view uses DBA_VIEWS. You have privileges to select from DBA_VIEW but not the privilige to grant select to other users.

This is the difference between:

```
Grant select on some_table to_some_user
```

and

`Grant select on some_table to_some_user with grant option`

In the latter case some_user can now grant select on some_table to other users;

Maybe you can accomplish what you want using ALL_VIEWS instead of DBA_VIEWS.

Comment: In my scenario USER_X tried performing the grant to MY_USER. They were also able to grant select for the table. But the error came when they tried to grant select on the view to MY_USER. So should a third user grant select with grant option to USER_X so they can grant access to MY_USER? It seems a bit convoluted, but then maybe I failed to understand the answer. A little more help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, there is a third user involved. The owner of DBA_VIEWS which is SYS. So your USER_X has somehow select granted on DBA_VIEW but not with grant option.
Try to base your view on ALL_VIEWS.
https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/oracle-data-dictionary-views-user-vs-all-vs-dba-views-100-level-basics/

Comment: Ok, so the third user needs to grant select with grant option (on the table or the view??) to USER_X, who, in turn, will grant select to MY_USER.

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to do that on dba_views. Use all_views.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb at this point, but I don't understand the part about using all_views instead of dba_views. I don't use it in any of the grants. The only place I used dba_views is to see the definition of MY_VIEW. And when I use `all_views` to get the view definition, I get the same result as `dba_views`.

Comment: Have you read the link above? all_views is available for all database users.

Answer (score 0):

When you received a privilege (e.g. `SELECT ON ABC_DEF.MY_VIEW`) then you cannot "forward" your privilege to somebody else.

In order to do so, you need the privilege with `WITH GRANT OPTION`, then you can forward the privilege to somebody else.